# Assign specific `QPushButton` to specific hardware button

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I would like to assign a specific hardware key to a `QPushButton` using Python and PyQt5.

The following code uses event filters to filter mouse button events for every `QPushButton`. Unfortunately, the click animation is not part of this assignment and just appears for left mouse clicks on every `QPushButton`.

Is there a way to implement the desired behaviour?

main.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QEvent, QObject, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        loadUi("mainwindow.ui", self)

        self.pushButton_left.installEventFilter(self)
        self.pushButton_middle.installEventFilter(self)
        self.pushButton_right.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and obj.objectName() == "pushButton_left":
                print("Left click")
            elif event.button() == Qt.MiddleButton and obj.objectName() == "pushButton_middle":
                print("Middle click")
            elif event.button() == Qt.RightButton and obj.objectName() == "pushButton_right":
                print("Right click")
        return QObject.event(obj, event)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

mainwindow.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1000</width>
    <height>200</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="locale">
   <locale language="English" country="UnitedKingdom"/>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
      <item row="0" column="0">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_left">
        <property name="text">
         <string>For left mouse button</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="1">
       <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>40</width>
          <height>20</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="2">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_middle">
        <property name="text">
         <string>For middle mouse button</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="3">
       <spacer name="horizontalSpacer_2">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>40</width>
          <height>20</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
      <item row="0" column="4">
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_right">
        <property name="text">
         <string>For right mouse button</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>1000</width>
     <height>28</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: I do not understand you, could you explain me better

Comment: The desired behaviour is that the `QPushButton` should show no click animation when the button is clicked.

Comment: @user9402680 A click animation for left mouse clicks is still part of every `QPushButton`.

Comment: @Atalanttore What you point out can be confusing, you do not want the appearance of the button pressed or you do not want to show the transition from un-pressed button to pressed button

Comment: @eyllanesc I mean both.

Comment: @Atalanttore I retried my code and I found out the incomplete part.When you click by DblClick, it is equal to leftbutton click, so I regulate it.My code becomes perfect, truely.

Comment: @user9402680 Great, your code implements the desired behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code.

**Explanation**

`QPushButton` is animated by `LeftButton` at default setting.
So we need to think how to animate it by `MidButton` and `RightButton`.

The truth of animation is similar or the same to the combination of  `setDown(True)` and `setDown(False)`.So I implement them when you click by `MidButton` and `RightButton` between `mousePressEvent` and `mouseReleaseEvent`.

But there is a problem to remain. Because `QPushButton` is animated by `LeftButton`,so the midbutton and the rightbutton are still animated by `LeftButton`.

You want to coincide the names each other.That is to say, LeftButton emits the animation by only the leftbutton.( MidButton emits the animation on only the midbutton,and RightButton emits the animation on only the rightbutton.)

For doing this, there is a way to implement return True in the `eventFilter`.
This means `eventFilter` serves both  the event of `eventFilter` and the event of the widget itself.

So, you need not to implement subclass for the pushButton and override it.

When you dblclick on the button, the animation also happens.So I regulated it.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QEvent, QObject, Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        loadUi("mainwindow.ui", self)

        self.pushButton_left.installEventFilter(self)
        self.pushButton_middle.installEventFilter(self)
        self.pushButton_right.installEventFilter(self)


    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonDblClick:
            if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and obj.objectName() == "pushButton_middle":
                return True
            elif event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and obj.objectName() == "pushButton_right":    
                return True
        if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and obj.objectName() == "pushButton_left":
                print("Left click")
            elif event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and obj.objectName() == "pushButton_middle":
                obj.setDown(False)
                return True
            elif event.button() == Qt.MiddleButton and obj.objectName() == "pushButton_middle":
                obj.setDown(True)
                print("Middle click")
            elif event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and obj.objectName() == "pushButton_right":            
                obj.setDown(False)
                return True
            elif event.button() == Qt.RightButton and obj.objectName() == "pushButton_right":
                obj.setDown(True)
                print("Right click")
        elif event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonRelease:
            if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and obj.objectName() == "pushButton_left":
                print("Left click")
            elif event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and obj.objectName() == "pushButton_middle":

                return True
            elif event.button() == Qt.MiddleButton and obj.objectName() == "pushButton_middle":
                obj.setDown(False)
                print("Middle click")
            elif event.button() == Qt.LeftButton and obj.objectName() == "pushButton_right":            

                return True
            elif event.button() == Qt.RightButton and obj.objectName() == "pushButton_right":
                obj.setDown(False)
                print("Right click")
        return QObject.event(obj, event)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()

    main_window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: That's a good start, but still all `QPushButton` show an animation when clicking with the left mouse button.

Comment: @Atalanttore I see, I miss it.Ok.